# Why does my character movement not feel right?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I tried using some code to move my character in canvas, but for some reason, the movement is very rough. When I press the movement keys, the character moves a bit, and then starts moving normally. Is there any way to make the initial key press more smooth? Here is the code I'm using:

```
var posX = 0;
var posY = 240;

var velX = 0;
var velY = 3;

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == "68") {
        velX = 3;
        posX += velX;
    }else if (event.keyCode == "65") {
        velX = 3;
        posX -= velX;
    }
});
```

Here is a live demo :
https://codepen.io/Twickz/pen/WmPWae

Also, velX and velY are velocity, and posX and posY are positions for my character.

Comment: Do you have a live example we can play around with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think keyboard buffer is at fault.

One solution bypassing it would be: the keydown event only starts the movement, and then you keep moving your character inside a loop (`setInterval`, or `requestAnimationFrame`), until keyup happens.

Something like this (the animation is maybe crude, but works as PoC):
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VRgNrQ

Answer (score -3):

Are you tried with keypress...keydown is evil